# How to evaluate this integral with a Dirac delta function?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, dirac-delta

$$P(s)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}xy \, \delta{(s-(x+y))}\, dxdy$$

$P(s)$ is the probability density of random variable $s=x+y$, who is a function of the two original random variables $x,y$. The peak occurs inside the limit of integration.

$P(x,y)=xy$ is the probability density of random variable $x,y$.

I tried to apply the property of Dirac delta function $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, \delta{(x-x_{0})}\, dx=f(x_{0}).$$

However, I am having trouble identify $x_{0}$.

**Edit: screenshot below**
[image][image][image]

This is the example the textbook use. For the exercise, $P(x,y)=xy$ instead of $1/36$, and I am kinda lost here.

Comment: Do the inner integral first. It is a slightly messy integral, depends on where $s$ lies.

Comment: so $\int_{0}^{1}x\, \delta{(s-(x+y))}\, dx$? But I am still not sure how to find $x_{0}$

Comment: It is when $s-(x-y) = 0$. What value of $x$ satisfies this?

Comment: You need the argument of the delta function to be $0$, so $x=s-y$

Comment: I see, thank both of you!

Comment: *Mathematica* (for $0 \leq s \leq 1$):  $$\frac{1}{6} \left(s^3-\left(s^3-3 s+2\right) \theta (s-1)\right) \theta (s)$$ where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: $x=s+y$, I think?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you for this, but it's outside the scope of the chapter where the exercise is, and the textbook didn't explicitly mention the Heaviside step function. But I will read more into this, thank you

Comment: @copper.hat $s=x+y$ as the textbook says, I will edit and include a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pedestrian approach:
$$\begin{align}P(s)~=~&\int_{[0,1]}\!dy~y \int_{[0,1]}\!dx~x~\delta{(s-(x+y))} \cr
~=~&\int_{[0,1]}\!dy~y \int_{\mathbb{R}}dx ~x~1_{[0,1]}(x) ~ \delta{(s-y-x)}\cr
~=~&\int_{[0,1]}\!dy~y(s-y)~1_{[0,1]}(s-y) \cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}dy ~y(s-y)~1_{[0,1]}(y)~1_{[s-1,s]}(y) \cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}dy ~y(s-y)~1_{[\max(0,s-1),\min(s,1)]}(y) \cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}dy ~y(s-y)~\left(1_{[0,1]}(s) 1_{[0,s]}(y) + 1_{[1,2]}(s) 1_{[s-1,1]}(y) \right) \cr
~=~&1_{[0,1]}(s) \left[ ~y^2\left(\frac{s}{2}-\frac{y}{3}\right)\right]^s_0  + 1_{[1,2]}(s) \left[ ~y^2\left(\frac{s}{2}-\frac{y}{3}\right)\right]^1_{s-1} \cr
~=~&1_{[0,1]}(s)~\frac{s^3}{6}  + 1_{[1,2]}(s) \left( -\frac{s^3}{6}+s-\frac{2}{3}\right),
\end{align}$$
where we have used [indicator/characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

From the 3rd line one can see that the map $s\mapsto P(s)$ is continuous. The last expression is continuous if the value the of indicator function is $1/2$ at the interval endpoints.

Comment: Hi there, there are some notation I am not quite familiar with. Is this a piecewise function? Starting on second line, $\int_{R}dx\, x\, 1_{[0,1]}\, (x) \, \delta (s-(x+y))$, what does $1_{[0,1]} (x)$ mean? On the third line, why are there two $(s-y)$? Sorry for the trivial question

Comment: I updated the answer.